# SQL SERVER: Can we keep recovery model as Bulk_Logged always instead of FULL recovery model

Tags: sql-server-2012

In one of my internal team discussion on recovery model we have been asked "Can we put out recovery model to Bulked_Logged always instead of FULL".

As we discussed, FULL recovery model will log each and every transaction. But there are some bulk operations which need not to be logged as this makes transaction logs grow a lot and for such situation we can switch to Bulk_Logged recovery model.

Since Bulk_Logged is a Minimally logged model, and all other transition like Insert,Update,Delete will always be logged by Bulk_logged. So why can't we keep Bulk_Logged model always, why do we switch back to FULL? Kindly suggest on this topic.

Comment: Point in time recovery.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith for your inputs, could you please help me with more details may be with some resource to understand in depth

Comment: Well shouldn't you read the document about recovery models: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server

Comment: That document says "Can recover to the end of any backup. Point-in-time recovery is not supported."